Difference between LoginManager and LoginButton in Facebook Login for Android
Following the Facebook Login for Android quickstart at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/, step 9 requires to register a Callback, where two options are mentioned to achieve this:

LoginManager
LoginButton

I am trying to understand the difference between those two options and corresponding pros and cons. I am experimenting with two options:

My btn: My button from scratch. When clicked, I invoke my own code.
FB code: I copied and pasted code from Facebook and it creates the button for me. When clicked, it takes me to a Facebook login page.


If I have clarity about the differences between the LoginManager and LoginButton approaches, I can focus on one solution or another with confidence of why it is the preferred path for my needs. Thank you.

Answer at loginButton.registerCallback cannot resolve method, by Jose L Ugia:

You do not need to register the callback on both the loginButton and
LoginManager.getInstance(). The former is for the loginButton flow,
the latter if you have your own button or login trigger. In fact it's
not clear on Facebook's documentation, not your fault.

